# Implementing of IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a code:

```
    public sealed class Sequence : IEnumerable<MyClass>
    {
        List<MyClass> _elements;

        public IEnumerator<MyClass> Getenumerator()
        {
            foreach (var item in _elements)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this._elements.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }


// ....

Sequence s = new Sequence();

// ...
// filling s with some data
// ...

foreach(MyClass c in s)
{
   // some action
}
```

That code doesn't want to compile.  It DOESNT want to compile. *Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator' requires '1' type arguments*

Help me to rewrite MyClass to support enumeration.

I tried several combinations, used Google. Everywhere examples of Enumerable and IEnumerator without generics.

Comment: Why complicating yourself?
Why not use IEnumerable<MyClass> or List<MyClass> without defining the Sequence class, which is very slow by the way.
It's much more flexible.

Comment: Because it's only a part of a class definition. There's some methods and properties inside it.

Answer (score 3):

Add the line:

```
using System.Collections;
```

You want to use `System.Collections.IEnumerator`, not `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>`.

Comment: I added that line and: ... ConsoleApplication1.Sequence' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ConsoleApplication1.MyClass>.GetEnumerator()'

Comment: @nik: Getenumerator method should be called GetEnumerator. C# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're just missing a `using` directive, since `IEnumerator` (of the non-generic variety) lives in `System.Collections`, and not `System.Collections.Generic` (which is included by default at the top of every source file).

So just define:

```
using System.Collections;
```

ando you're good to go.

Comment: no, no good. ConsoleApplication1.Sequence' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ConsoleApplication1.MyClass>.GetEnumerator()'

Comment: No idea what you're doing wrong, but why not just use the VS smart tag to auto-implement the interface? Guaranteed to get things right then.

Comment: @Noldorin, I want to implement generics --> IEnumerable<T> but it seems there's no samples. All things that i can find is all about IEnumerable. Can you give me any example of IEnumerable<SomeClass> with internal collection for example List<SomeClass> _elements;

Comment: There is a typo in your code: Its GetEnumerator not Getenumerator (casing is important).

Comment: Hah, wasn't even looking at that function. Good spot.... always the silliest mistakes.